# Need proper hashCode when comparing Object with unordered pair of integers as variables

Tags: java, comparison, equals, hashcode

I have a class

```
final class BuildingPair {

    int mBA;
    int mBB;

    public BuildingPair(int pBuildingA,int pBuildingB) {
        mBA = pBuildingA;
        mBB = pBuildingB;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + mBA;
        result = prime * result + mBB;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        BuildingPair other = (BuildingPair) obj;
        if ((mBA==other.mBA&&mBB==other.mBB)||(mBA==other.mBB&&mBB==other.mBA)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to compare two objects , and when both have the same buildings ids they are equal

so they need to be equal in both directions when :

```
BuildingPair(1,2) vs BuildingPair(2,1) 
BuildingPair(1,2) vs BuildingPair(1,2)
BuildingPair(2,1) vs BuildingPair(1,2)
```

i think equals method is ok, but hashcode is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need something that computes the same result whether passed `A,B` or `B,A`. There may be far more subtle solutions, but I'd probably just go for:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return mBA * mBB;
}
```

Or anything else which uses an operator that is commutative.

---

Alternatively, you could change your constructor so that it always stores `min(a,b)` in `mBA` and `max(a,b)` in `mBB` - you can then simplify your comparison code and keep your hash code as it currently is.

Comment: Depending on the values of mBA, mBB, multiplication or addition may result in overflow (and subtle bugs).

Comment: @paul-g - all we care about is that when overflow occurs, the result is still deterministic, which I believe it is with Java.

Answer (score 3):

You need a symmetric hashcode (`hashcode(a,b) == hashcode(b,a)`), for example:

```
return mBB ^ mBA;
```

(your current code is not symmetric - for example: hascode (2,1) = 1024 but hashcode(1,2) = 994)

Note: this is inspired from the hashcode of `Long`:

```
return (int)(value ^ (value >>> 32));
```

Answer (score 3):

If they are unordered you can use an arbitrary order which simplifies the rest of the code.

```
public BuildingPair(int pBuildingA,int pBuildingB) {
    mBA = Math.min(pBuildingA, pBuildingB);
    mBB = Math.max(pBuildingA, pBuildingB);
}
```

code the rest of the methods as normal and BuildingPair(2,1) will be exactly the same as BuildingPair(1,2)